# Reading an XML file results in Termination due to an unhandled exception

Tags: c#, xml

I have created an XML file with the following basic info:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MailSettings>
    <To>some@email.com</To>
    <From>another@email.com</From>
    <Server>smtp.email.com</Server>
    <Port>25</Port>
    <Subject>E-mail subject</Subject>
</MailSettings>
```

I'm trying to read in each tag with the following code:

```
public static void ReadXml(string send)
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\MailSettings.xml");

    XmlNodeList xnList = doc.SelectNodes("/MailSettings");
    foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
    {
        string To = xn["To"].InnerText;
        string From = xn["From"].InnerText;
        string Server = xn["Server"].InnerText;
        string Port = xn["Port"].InnerText;
        string Subject = xn["Subject"].InnerText;

        WriteErrorLog("Sending an e-mail with the following settings");
        WriteErrorLog("To: " + To + " From: " + From + " Server: " + Server + " Port: " + Port + " Subject: " + Subject);
    }
}
```

However it's failing with the following error:

> "The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception."
>       Exception Info: System.Xml.XmlException
>       Stack:
>          at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(System.String, System.String)
>          at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseRootLevelWhitespace()
>          at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
>          at System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(System.Xml.XmlDocument, System.Xml.XmlReader, Boolean)
>          at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(System.Xml.XmlReader)
>          at System.Xml.XmlDocument.LoadXml(System.String)
>          at AEMKeepAlive.Library.ReadXml(System.String)
>          at AEMKeepAlive.AEMKeepAlive.ServiceMonitor()
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

I'm not sure what I have done wrong and can't seem to get it working.

Comment: What is settings in your x path?

Comment: I'm not sure why you get an Exception, but you are selecting the node Settings but the actual XML has a node MailSettings and nothing just called Settings.

Comment: Your code is looking for a root node called `Settings` whereas in your file it is `MailSettings`

Comment: Thanks for the spot. I've since corrected 'Settings' to 'MailSettings', unfortunately I'm still getting the same message. :(

Comment: `LoadXml` is for loading an XML string. Use `Load` to load a file.

Comment: Learn to use the debugger.

Comment: I think there is white spaces before the first tag.  XML want to see the XML definition line on line 1.  I would read file as text, then use trim to remove any white spaces at beginning of data.